# Sparse matrix inputs to keras layer_dense in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, sparse-matrix

**Edit**:  Wide open to possibilities in `torch for R` too.

How can columns from a `dgCMatrix` in R be fed as inputs to a `layer_dense` when using the keras R API?

My data is too large to consider coercing it from sparse to dense, and it is too inefficient to coerce small chunks to dense for minibatch updates.

**Minimum reproducible example:**

```
library(Matrix)
library(keras)
library(reticulate)
library(magrittr)

inputs <- rsparsematrix(10000, 1000, 0.1)
targets <- keras::to_categorical(sample(0:9, 1000, replace = T), num_classes = 10)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 100, activation = "relu", input_shape = nrow(inputs)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = ncol(targets), activation = "softmax")

compile(model,
        loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
        metrics = c("accuracy"))

fit(model, t(as.matrix(inputs)), targets, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a `dgCMatrix`?

Comment: @Quinten `inputs` in my example is a `dgCMatrix`.  It's just CSC sparse format.

Comment: You probably want to convert to [tf.sparse.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor). This is quite similar to dgTMatrix format in R, so that could be a first step in the conversion.